# TypeError; Must use key word argument or key function in Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python, trying to port a script in 2.x to 3.x i am encountering the error "TypeError; must use key word argument or key function" in Python 3.x. Below is the piece of code.

```
def resort_working_array(self, chosen_values_arr, num):
    for item in self.__working_arr[num]:
        data_node = self.__pairs.get_node_info(item)

        new_combs = []
        for i in range(0, self.__n):
            # Numbers of new combinations to be created if this item is appended to array
            new_combs.append( set([pairs_storage.key(z) for z in xuniqueCombinations( chosen_values_arr+[item], i+1)]) - self.__pairs.get_combs()[i] )
        # Weighting the node
        item.weights =  [-len(new_combs[-1])]  # Node that creates most of new pairs is the best
        item.weights += [len(data_node.out)]   # Less used outbound connections most likely to produce more new pairs while search continues
        item.weights += [len(x) for x in reversed(new_combs[:-1])]
        item.weights += [-data_node.counter]   # Less used node is better
        item.weights += [-len(data_node.in_)]  # Otherwise we will prefer node with most of free inbound connections; somehow it works out better ;)

    self.__working_arr[num].sort(key = lambda a,b: cmp(a.weights, b.weights))
```

Comment: I can't run this since it isn't an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so it's hard to fully diagnose the problem. But at a quick glance, the `key` argument's lambda is only supposed to take one argument. Have you tried `sort(key = lambda a: a.weights)`?

Comment: oh!! Perfect this works. Thanks Kevin, u saved me a lot of time.

Comment: This  is a new addition to Python3, also a good read is relevant PEP: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/

Answer (score 20):

Looks like the problem is in this line.

```
self.__working_arr[num].sort( key = lambda a,b: cmp(a.weights, b.weights) )
```

The `key` callable should take only one argument. Try:

```
self.__working_arr[num].sort(key = lambda a: a.weights)
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, what if I need the two elements of array to create two new numbers and sort the array based on comparison between the new numbers, like this: https://pastebin.com/NqTn5TgN  
How do I convert it into lambda form?

Comment: @featuresky - FWIW I hit a similar issue to you. I wouldn't highly recommended it (mostly because I don't really know what I'm doing) but I just posted a hack (as an answer) that may be of some value to you?!

Answer (score 7):

The exact same error message appears if you try to pass the *key* parameter as a positional parameter.

Wrong:

```
sort(lst, myKeyFunction)
```

Correct:

```
sort(lst, key=myKeyFunction)
```

Python 3.6.6

Comment: the interface of the sort function is `sort(*, key=None, reverse=False)`, note that the first parameter takes an arbitrary number of positional argument  (although normally you just pass one object, a list for example), so you _must_ use named argument for `key` and `reverse`.

Comment: Where does `sort` function come from? I can't find it as built in. However, I could import it from *numpy*

Comment: @mayid lists should have it (ex. `lst.sort()`) as an in-place mutation of the data structure. See http://python3porting.com/preparing.html

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the [answer by @Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29944332/3363571) - and more specifically the comment/question by @featuresky:

Using [functools.cmp_to_key](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) and reimplementing *cmp* (as noted in the [porting guide](https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparisons.html)) I have a hacky workaround for a scenario where two elements can be compared via lambda form. To use the OP as an example; instead of:

```
self.__working_arr[num].sort( key = lambda a,b: cmp(a.weights, b.weights) )
```

You can use this:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

[...]

def cmp(x, y): return (x > y) - (x < y)
self.__working_arr[num].sort(key=cmp_to_key(lambda a,b: cmp(a.weights, b.weights)))
```

Admittedly, I'm somewhat new to Python myself and don't really have a good handle on Python 2. I'm sure the code could be rewritten in a much better/cleaner way and I'd certainly love to hear a "proper" way to do this.

On the other hand, in my case this was a handy hack for a old Python 2 script (updated to Python 3) that I don't have time/energy to "properly" understand and rewrite right now.

Beyond the fact that it works, I would certainly not recommend wide usage of this hack! But I figured that it was worth sharing.